# preventDefault not working if the link is not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I have this code

```
$("#mainPageSlider").click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log("I am here");
]);
```

My html is

```
<a href="admin/category/cloths">
  <img src="image/catalog/myimage.jpg" alt="Slider" id="mainPageSlider">
```

if the link admin/category/cloths exists, my code displays console.log message however if the link does not exists, it seems to ignore my click code and just goes to another page for not found pages. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you binding the click handler to the img element? What is the default behaviour for a click on an image? Have you considered preventing default for the *anchor*?

Comment: add function argument "event"

Comment: sorry so embarrassed to even ask this question now. It was me being stupid. Need to look at the propagation a bit deeper. works now!